# Inverse laplace of given function

Tags: laplace-transform

Unfortunately, I have no attempt. Could you give me some hints?
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{e^{-s}-1}{s(s^2+4)}\right\}=?$$
The usual method I would use to do such a question is to refer to a table of Laplace Transforms and some basics.

Comment: Referring to a table of Laplace Transform and some basics

Comment: Mathematica gives $\frac{1}{2} \left(\theta (t-1) \sin ^2(1-t)-\sin ^2(t)\right)$...

Comment: Here are some hints. You can apply the following 3 properties. I would first use Property **1**, then **3**, then **2**:
$$~$$
**Property 1:** Linearity
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{a\cdot F(s)+b\cdot G(s)\}=a\cdot f(t)+b\cdot g(t)$$
**Property 2:** Second Shifting Theorem ($u(t)$ is the unit step function)
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{e^{-cs}F(s)\}=u(t-c)f(t-c)$$
**Property 3:** Convolution
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F(s)G(s)\}=\int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau)~d\tau$$
Note that here I define $F(s)=\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}$ and $G(s)=\mathscr{L}\{g(t)\}$.
Could you please show us what you get after applying them?